# How can we process only the data in the base class without cloning them into derived classes?

Tags: c#, oop, unity-game-engine, inheritance

My game has multiple game modes. Each game type has a different game logic. But some parts are shared.
I want to store shared parts (shared logic, game data etc.) in the base class for clean code and
override game mode related parts in derived class. My goals and example codes below.

- **GameManager** is base class of game modes (normal, versus, tutorial
  etc.)
- Only this class has game data and derived classes should use it. (player data, properties etc.)
- This class has button methods, common methods. This common methods should be override by derived classes.

GameManager.cs

```
public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    //Example game data (this data only should store in base class)
    [SerializeField] protected List<Player> players = new List<Player>();
    protected bool someOneWon = false;
    protected int winnerIndex = -1;
    protected int botCount = 4;

    public virtual void StartGame()
    {
        MenuManager.Instance.GamePanelActivateUI();
        InitBots();
    }

    private void InitBots()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < botCount; i++)
        {
             Player bot = Instantiate(UIManager.Instance.PlayerPrefab).GetComponent<Player>();
             bot.InitPlayer(PlayerType.Bot); //Player data initialize here
             players.Add(bot);
        }
    }

    public void SomeButton()
    {
        //This method attached button

        //Throws null error because its null on GameManager
        Debug.Log("Player.coin" + players[1].coin) 
    }
}
```

- Derived classes can have own properties & methods.
- They can access parent class properties & methods and override them for own game logic.
- **Derived class shouldn't duplicate base class game data (player data etc.).** They should reach base
  class.

NormalGame.cs

```
public class NormalGame: GameManager
{
      //Related Normal Game Properties

      public override void StartGame()
      {
           base.StartGame();
           StartCoroutine(NormalGameCycle());
      }

      IEnumerator NormalGameCycle()
      {
           //normal game logic
      }
}
```

VersusGame.cs

```
public class VersusGame: GameManager
{
      //Related Versus Properties & Methods
}
```

TutorialGame.cs

```
public class TutorialGame: GameManager
{
      //Related Tutorial Properties & Methods
}
```

When i try that like an architecture base class data duplicate all derived class and it causes null reference errors on button clicks or running some code on base side. **When i call from derived class like base.StartGame() data will be initializing on derived class not on base class.** I want the processed data to be included only in base class. I am waiting for your suggestions, thanks for reading.

[image: GameManager properties are null after initializing]

[image: NormalGame properties are initialized on it.]

Comment: Your last paragraph is pretty unclear to me. I can´t see any code-duplicates nor wherfe an NRE would occur. Could you please provide the code for at leats one derived class also?

Comment: For example NRE occurs on SomeButton method. Because players list and all other data is null. They are initializing on NormalGame class but not init on GameManager. class.

Answer (score 0):

I had a hard time following the problem you're having, but I suspect you are expecting your class objects to behave as though they were static classes, when you're actually dealing with separate object instances of your two classes.

Unfortunately, simply changing your classes to be static won't resolve the issue, as static classes are sealed in C#, and cannot be inherited from, so you may need to revise your approach to this problem.

Comment: Yes i don't want to store all game mode codes in 1 script (gamemanager). I want to seperate them to make it look clean. But inheritance doesn't fit for this situtation i think. If you have any different approach about game-mode based architecture please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is hiding in plain sight in your question: "data, properties"!

These sort of things are solved using [composition rather than inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance).

What you need is something like Unity's [Scriptable Object](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-ScriptableObject.html), which is defined as:

*A **data** container that you can use to save large amounts of **data, independent of class instances***.

It will allow you to configure various properties that you might want to change between different game modes while storing it in a field.

```cs
public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameOptions gameOptions;
}

[CreateAssetMenu(menuName = "Data/Game Options")]
public class GameOptions : ScriptableObject
{
    public List<string> options;
}
```